# sending email on php

Tags: php

I have this code to send email.and I got no error in sending email.

```
 if(mailSender()){
            echo 'meiled.';
        }else {
        die('not sent');    
      }
    function mailSender() {
        $to = 'info@fcrop.com';
        $subject = 'An Abstract Submitted';
        $message = 'An Abstract Submitted Recently In ICNBA.org';
        $headers = 'Frominfo@icnba.org';
        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    }
```

it does not send email.

Comment: Are you working on local system? or using some live server to run this code?

Comment: your function `mailSender() ` always return `null` null like false. you get always `not sent` message

Comment: You check the value returned by function `mailSender()` in the first line of code but the function `mailSender()` doesn't return anything. And "nothing" means `NULL` and [`NULL` is `FALSE`](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php)

Comment: Mohammad you need to go along with correct as well as descriptive answer.

Comment: Mohammd you said it `I think it does not relative with reply, because mail send nothing` on the marked answer. So its confusing, can you please tell if is it so, then why you marked the answer?

Comment: could you please vote my question? I'm question ban. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the if expression evaluates a boolean, and `mailSender()` returns none.

Add this to your function:

```
return mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

For more information about see the php documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php

Comment: could you please vote my question? I'm question ban. :(

Comment: I guess there is a reason for that ban, how about giving some positive answers?

Comment: yes there was reason, they said "your question was not clear, you should rewrite your question to clear way". and I did this. I changed my question and I wrote it clear

Comment: You know the culture here is that you should have tried finding out why your code doesn't work the way it should before asking a question. And explain in the question what you have tried so far.

Comment: I know that. but I see no mistake in my question.

Comment: Well the way I see it is that this is more a statement than a question: the code doesn't work. Looks like a call to fix the code. You didn't tell what doesn't work, php usually gives you an error message. You also did not explain what you have tried so far etc

Comment: yes you were right about my this sentence, it was extra for the question. I changed it. but I got no error on this code.

Comment: of course I solve my problem. this question is for long time ago

Comment: Yes it is, be sure next time to highlight the fact that you didn't got any error, that you have tried to find the problem and try to be specific what it is that you want help with.

Comment: thanks a lot. you really helped me. I appreciate you

Answer (score 3):

You need to change:

`$headers = 'Frominfo@icnba.org';` to `$headers = 'From: info@icnba.org';`

and

`mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);` to `return mail(`... to return the value otherwise mailSender won't return anything.

If the mail is not being sent this may have many reasons from php.ini settings over local MTA misconfiguration to unmatched SPF records. Check your mail logs to see if there are any errors.

Comment: edit you answer because header should be `$headers = 'From:info@icnba.org'."\r\n";`

Comment: "\r\n" should not be necessary for the only one or last header?!

Comment: look exampel down for more information this not last line, last line need "\r\n\r\n"

Comment: I think it does not relative with reply, because mail send nothing

Comment: @MohammadAghayari   you said it `I think it does not relative with reply, because mail send nothing` and still marked the answer why?

Comment: could you please vote my question? I'm question ban. :(

Answer (score 0):

@user3173842 look standart rfc2822 for get more information last header line need \r\n\r\n http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2822.html

```
From: "Joe Q. Public" <john.q.public@example.com> \r\n
To: Mary Smith <mary@x.test>, jdoe@example.org, Who? <one@y.test> \r\n
Cc: <boss@nil.test>, "Giant; \"Big\" Box" <sysservices@example.net> \r\n
Date: Tue, 1 Jul 2003 10:52:37 +0200 \r\n
Message-ID: <5678.21-Nov-1997@example.com> \r\n
\r\n
Hi everyone. is body
```

this is answer for show example header
sorry for offtop

Comment: I know that, but I thought php would add these since they always need to be there and it's the `headers` parameter... And I just read this example: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#example-3898

Comment: bad way use `mail()` function because you send wrong header to,from etc, and mail service banned you for it. better way use library for example `PHPmailer` and etc

Comment: It makes no difference if you add `\r\n` to the last header because $headers is trimmed by `mail`: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/71c19800258ee3a9548af9a5e64ab0a62d1b1d8e/ext/standard/mail.c#L122

Comment: @user3173842 wery good comment and argumentation respect. it's rely trim thank you

Comment: could you please vote my question? I'm question ban. :(